# How to do a conditional max to return the last purchase from the customer for each warranty claim?

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

Hi I have a data table that looks like this

| OrderID | Date | Product Name | CustomerID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 476070 | February 24,2021 | WARRANTY CLAIM | ABC123 |
| 476069 | February 22,2021 | PRODUCT C | ABC123 |
| 476068 | February 10,2021 | WARRANTY CLAIM | ABC123 |
| 476067 | February 1,2021 | WARRANTY CLAIM | ABC123 |
| 476064 | January 23,2021 | PRODUCT B | ABC123 |
| 476051 | January 10,2021 | WARRANTY CLAIM | ABC123 |
| 475023 | January 1 , 2021 | PRODUCT A | ABC123 |

What I am trying to achieve is for each warranty claim , I want to get the last product purchase of that customer.

So meaning that the output I want to achieve is like this

| OrderID | Date | Product Name | CustomerID | LASTPRODUCTPURCHASE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 476070 | February 24,2021 | WARRANTY CLAIM | ABC123 | PRODUCT C |
| 476069 | February 22,2021 | PRODUCT C | ABC123 | NULL |
| 476068 | February 10,2021 | WARRANTY CLAIM | ABC123 | PRODUCT B |
| 476067 | February 1,2021 | WARRANTY CLAIM | ABC123 | PRODUCT B |
| 476064 | January 23,2021 | PRODUCT B | ABC123 | NULL |
| 476051 | January 10,2021 | WARRANTY CLAIM | ABC123 | PRODUCT A |
| 475023 | January 1 , 2021 | PRODUCT A | ABC123 | NULL |

I have tried LAG and MAXIF but it returns either the previous order or the latest order for that particular customer. I need to have the **LAST** product purchase of that customer and only applicable for warranty claim orders.

**I am getting this output for the CTE solution**

[image]

This is the query I ran :

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, MAX(CASE WHEN productName <> 'Warranty Service' OR productName <> 'Warranty Collect' OR productName <> 'Warranty Inspection' OR productName <> 'Delivery' THEN id END) OVER
                  (PARTITION BY vpn ORDER BY ordercompleted_at) MaxOrderID
    FROM baterikudatawarehouse.bateriku_production.BaterikuOrderTrafficJune2020
    where orderStatus = 'completed' and vpn = 'QMY70' order by ordercompleted_at DESC
)

SELECT t1.id ,t1.ordercompleted_at, t1.productName, t1.vpn,
       CASE WHEN t1.productName = 'Warranty Service' OR t1.productName = 'Warranty Collect' OR t1.productName = 'Delivery' OR t1.productName = 'Warranty Inspection'
            THEN t2.productName END AS LASTPRODUCTPURCHASE
FROM cte t1

INNER JOIN baterikudatawarehouse.bateriku_production.BaterikuOrderTrafficJune2020 t2
    ON t2.vpn = t1.vpn AND
       t2.id = t1.MaxOrderId ORDER BY t1.ordercompleted_at DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is another approach using `lead` :

```
select orderid,Date,productname,customerid,
       case when productname = 'WARRANTY CLAIM' then
       max(lastpn)over(partition by customerid order by orderid) else null end as LASTPRODUCTPURCHASE 
       from (
             select tb.*, 
             case when lead(productname)over(partition by customerid order by OrderID desc) = 'WARRANTY CLAIM' then null 
             else lead(productname)over(partition by customerid order by OrderID desc) end as lastpn
             from tb
            ) a
```

here is [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=79c3fe32ca5c99df5f26a771a9a5331e), include @Tim Biegeleisen answer which IMO a better choose if CTE is allow.
also I have add more rows with sample data in db<>fiddle for better examine.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. Any caveats with this query since it's using lead?

Comment: @SyedAriff actually I can't think of any problem it will occur, I guess the only thing to watch out is the `order by`, make sure the data do follow with right order.

Answer (score 1):

One approach, which first finds the latest orders for each customer, at each point in time:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, MAX(CASE WHEN ProductName <> 'WARRANTY CLAIM' THEN OrderID END) OVER
                  (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY Date) MaxOrderID
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT t1.OrderID, t1.Date, t1.ProductName, t1.CustomerID,
       CASE WHEN t1.ProductName = 'Warranty Claim'
            THEN t2.ProductName END AS LASTPRODUCTPURCHASE
FROM cte t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t2.CustomerID = t1.CustomerID AND
       t2.OrderID = t1.MaxOrderId;
```

Note that the join back to the original table pulls in the latest product name from the most recent non warranty transaction.

Comment: Highly appreciate if you could include a fiddle with this answer

Comment: I'm on a cell phone right now, and I have not tested the above code.

Comment: Okay I have tried but it does not seem to work. Warranty Claim returns Warranty Claim in the LASTPRODUCTPURCHASE column

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen watch out the case sensitive.

Comment: I posted my output from the above query in the question